# How to add an SQL subquery, using averages based on other conditions?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I’m trying to run a subquery as part of the Select columns (on MS Access)

I have two queries that work fine on their own.
The only difference is one just contains records in the last 7 days, and the other contains after 7 days and less than 372 days.

What I'm trying is to include the latter average column as part of the first query.

This the first one for last 7 days

```
SELECT Customers.customerName, OrderProducts.productCode, Avg(OrderProducts.Quantity) AS AvgOfQuantity
FROM (Customers INNER JOIN OrderData ON Customers.customerID = OrderData.customerID) INNER JOIN OrderProducts ON OrderData.orderID = OrderProducts.orderID
WHERE (((OrderData.dateAdded)>=Date()-7))
GROUP BY Customers.customerName, OrderProducts.productCode;
```

And the 2nd one, after 7 days for a year

```
SELECT Customers.customerName, OrderProducts.productCode, Avg(OrderProducts.Quantity) AS AvgOfQuantity
FROM (Customers INNER JOIN OrderData ON Customers.customerID = OrderData.customerID) INNER JOIN OrderProducts ON OrderData.orderID = OrderProducts.orderID
WHERE (((OrderData.dateAdded)>=Date()-372 And (OrderData.dateAdded)<=Date()-7))
GROUP BY Customers.customerName, OrderProducts.productCode
```

Where my attempt at adding the latter as a subquery, just calculates the average on them all, rather than by row.

```
SELECT Customers.customerName, OrderProducts.productCode, Avg(OrderProducts.Quantity) AS AvgOfQuantity, (Select Avg(OrderProducts.Quantity) 
FROM (Customers INNER JOIN OrderData ON Customers.customerID = OrderData.customerID) INNER JOIN OrderProducts ON OrderData.orderID = OrderProducts.orderID
WHERE (((OrderData.dateAdded)>=Date()-372 And (OrderData.dateAdded)<=Date()-7))) As AvgfromPastYear
FROM (Customers INNER JOIN OrderData ON Customers.customerID = OrderData.customerID) INNER JOIN OrderProducts ON OrderData.orderID = OrderProducts.orderID
WHERE (((OrderData.dateAdded)>=Date()-7))
GROUP BY Customers.customerName, OrderProducts.productCode;
```

Comment: You can create a view from the first query, and then select with the second query from it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't think of saving the first query, rather then over complicating it.  It works now :-D